# Laravel Jetsream multiple user sources with multiple routes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-jetstream

I must two types of user on my laravel project.
I alredy separated Models https://samuelstancl.me/multiple-user-models-with-laravel-jetstream but now I need to make separeted routes and controllers for each login.

So basically, if I have two Models
OriginalUsers
PortalUsers

I need to make two login Controllers with urls

> /original/login

> /portal/login

I found like I need to edit JetstreamProvider, but I'm not sure what I really must to put here.

Answer (score 0):

Why separated your models? You can use one modal for your process.

Just add the user role to your user table.

simple:

user_role = 'original' or user_role = 'portal'

Comment: I still need to have separate routes to login pages.